# How can we match JSON values returned as columns with rows appropriately

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Here is the sample JSON value returned from Azure LogAnalytics and I am not sure how to get a specific property's value "AuditEventID" & "TimeGenerated". `enter code here`

```
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "PrimaryResult",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "TenantId",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "SourceSystem",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "TimeGenerated",
          "type": "datetime"
        },
        {
          "name": "OperationName",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "Category",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "ResultType",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "ResultDescription",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "CorrelationId",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "Identity",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "Properties",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "Type",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "************************",
          "Microsoft Intune",
          "2023-02-27T09:24:01.2829Z",
          "*****************",
          "AuditLogs",
          "Success",
          "None",
          "*************************",
          "user@contoso.info",
          "{\"ActivityDate\":\"2/27/2023 9:24:01 AM\",\"ActivityResultStatus\":1,\"ActivityType\":0,\"Actor\":{\"ActorType\":1,\"Application\":\"d1ddf0e4-d672-4dae-b554-9d5bdfd93547\",\"ApplicationName\":\"Microsoft Intune PowerShell\",\"IsDelegatedAdmin\":false,\"Name\":null,\"ObjectId\":\"b88f2ad0-6b63-4dc8-8fde-d2beaf38996b\",\"PartnerTenantId\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\",\"UserPermissions\":[\"*\"],\"UPN\":\"user@contoso.info\"},\"AdditionalDetails\":\"\",\"AuditEventId\":\"53b6081c-bb44-4eca-8f75-e6fa71513fd4\",\"Category\":1,\"RelationId\":null,\"TargetDisplayNames\":[\"<null>\"],\"TargetObjectIds\":[\"4487b7d7-79b8-4625-85e0-77477db8cd1c\"],\"Targets\":[{\"ModifiedProperties\":[{\"Name\":\"DeviceManagementAPIVersion\",\"Old\":null,\"New\":\"5022-12-08\"}],\"Name\":null}]}",
          "IntuneAuditLogs"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please share your views on how we can address this situation.tried several ways yet unable to figure out how this can be extracted out to a compose action because I needed to use these properties as a input to next actions.

Comment: So for `TimeGenerated` are you wanting/expecting `datetime` to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

**I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:**

**You can directly replicate logic app using **code view** given at end header of my answer.**

**Firstly, I parsed json:**

**Here content is your input and schema is given after below picture.**

[image]

[image]

**Schema :**

```
{
    "properties": {
        "tables": {
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "columns": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "type": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "rows": {
                        "items": {
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": "array"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "type": "object"
            },
            "type": "array"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

**Then in ForEach Loop:**

**Firstly:**

[image]

**Then In Compose:**

**Here you will get Time generated Output :**

```
Items('For_each')?['rows'][0][2]
```

[image]

**Then in compose 2 :**

```
json(Items('For_each')?['rows'][0][9])
```

[image]

**Then in Compose 3:**

**Here you will get AuditEventid:**

```
outputs('Compose_2')['AuditEventId']
```

[image]

**Now you can use Compose and Compose 3 for your future use in code.**

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

**Code view:**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": ":@{Items('For_each')?['rows'][0][2]}\n",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Compose_2": {
                        "inputs": "@json(Items('For_each')?['rows'][0][9])",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Compose_3": {
                        "inputs": "@outputs('Compose_2')['AuditEventId']",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose_2": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Compose"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['tables']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "emo",
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": {
                        "tables": [
                            {
                                "columns": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "TenantId",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "SourceSystem",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "TimeGenerated",
                                        "type": "datetime"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "OperationName",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Category",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "ResultType",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "ResultDescription",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "CorrelationId",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Identity",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Properties",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Type",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "name": "PrimaryResult",
                                "rows": [
                                    [
                                        "************************",
                                        "Microsoft Intune",
                                        "2023-02-27T09:24:01.2829Z",
                                        "*****************",
                                        "AuditLogs",
                                        "Success",
                                        "None",
                                        "*************************",
                                        "user@contoso.info",
                                        "{\"ActivityDate\":\"2/27/2023 9:24:01 AM\",\"ActivityResultStatus\":1,\"ActivityType\":0,\"Actor\":{\"ActorType\":1,\"Application\":\"d1ddf0e4-d672-4dae-b554-9d5bdfd93547\",\"ApplicationName\":\"Microsoft Intune PowerShell\",\"IsDelegatedAdmin\":false,\"Name\":null,\"ObjectId\":\"b88f2ad0-6b63-4dc8-8fde-d2beaf38996b\",\"PartnerTenantId\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\",\"UserPermissions\":[\"*\"],\"UPN\":\"user@contoso.info\"},\"AdditionalDetails\":\"\",\"AuditEventId\":\"53b6081c-bb44-4eca-8f75-e6fa71513fd4\",\"Category\":1,\"RelationId\":null,\"TargetDisplayNames\":[\"<null>\"],\"TargetObjectIds\":[\"4487b7d7-79b8-4625-85e0-77477db8cd1c\"],\"Targets\":[{\"ModifiedProperties\":[{\"Name\":\"DeviceManagementAPIVersion\",\"Old\":null,\"New\":\"5022-12-08\"}],\"Name\":null}]}",
                                        "IntuneAuditLogs"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "tables": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "columns": {
                                            "items": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "name": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "type": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "type": "object"
                                            },
                                            "type": "array"
                                        },
                                        "name": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "rows": {
                                            "items": {
                                                "items": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "type": "array"
                                            },
                                            "type": "array"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```